# How to Format Includes List for Py2app?

Tags: python, py2app

I have an app organized across several folders:

- models
- views
- controllers
- data_and_execution.

I'm trying to build the app using Py2app, however, I'm getting import errors when running the app such as:

```
"4/27/16 9:52:29.252 PM main[63983]: ImportError: No module named controllers.available_balances_controller"
```

I believe it's because I have the 'includes' list setup wrong.

I've included all the folders.  Do I really have to include each and every script name & path in the app?

If so, is there a way to output all the app dependencies using Pycharm?

Here's the way I have the options in settings.py now:

```
OPTIONS = {'argv_emulation': True,
           'iconfile':'command_line_icon.ico',
           'includes': ['controllers', 'data_and_execution', 'models', 'views'],}
```

If I have scripts in the 'controllers', 'data_and_execution', 'models', 'views' folders, how do I reference them in the 'includes' list so Py2app finds them?

Answer (score 0):

Try this
`'includes' :['controllers.your_file_without_ext', ....`

If it still not work try importing them as package
`'packages': ['controllers', 'data_and_execution', 'models', 'views'],`